# How to split the string into multiple sub-strings with python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

I am having these lines in text file. First line is the column name. Data is not in fixed format so I cannot split it with slicing the string with index range.

```
a                    b              c            d             e               f              g          h           i          j
SEMESTER            24             18                          0               74            28          0          74        VISU
Burf               13+1/2         9+5/8                         0             1,122          320          0         1,122      VISU
1ST                8+3/4          4+1/2                                      8,192         1,280       3,570       8,192       CBL
Burf              13+1/2         9+5/8           36            0             1,235          592          0        1,235       VISU
SEMESTER            26             16           Line           0              160           212           0         160       CALC
                   8+3/4            7            26            0             8,243          734         970       8,243       CBL
OPEN WORK          6+1/8                      WiseLine        8243           10,239                                               
SEMESTER            19             16         line pipe        0              105             0           0         105       CALC
SEMESTER                           16          65#            0                             100          0         89         CALC
2ND                 6+1/8          4+1/2                        0             9,257
SEMESTER            20              16          65#             0            89             100          0         89         CALC
2ND               6+1/8           4+1/2                         0           9,257
```

I want to split all the lines and need output like this.

```
["SEMESTER", "24", "18", "", "0", "74", "28", "0", "74", "SUVI"]
["BURF", "13+1/2", "9+5/8", "", "0", "1122", "320", "0", "1122", "SUVI"] 
["1ST", "8+3/4", "4+1/2", "", "", "8192", "1280", "3570", "8192", "BCL"]
["BURF", "13+1/2", "9+5/8", "36", "0", "1235", "592", "0", "1235", "SUVI"]
["SEMESTER", "26", "16", "Line", "0", "160", "212", "0", "160", "CALC"]
["", "8+3/4", "7", "26", "0", "8243", "734", "970", "8243", "BCL"]
["OPEN WORK", "6+1/8", "", "Wiseline", "8243", "10239", "", "", "", ""]
["SEMESTER", "19", "16", "line wise", "0", "105", "0", "0", "105", "CALC"]
["SEMESTER", "", "16", "65#", "0", "", "100", "0", "89", "CALC"]
["2ND", "6+1/8", "4+1/2", "", "0", "9257", "", "", "", ""]
["SEMESTER", "20", "16", "65#", "0", "89", "100", "0", "89", "CALC"]
["2ND", " 6+1/8", "4+1/2", "", "0", "9257", "", "", "", ""]
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me in this problem.

Comment: Just a quick question, do you have access to how this data is being generated? Is there a way to add some sort of `NIL` value for "blank" values?

Comment: If you were to print the data, would it be possible to draw straight vertical lines in between the column data? If so, you can use fixed formatting.

Comment: I am afraid @Levi Muniz,  there is no way we can add NIL in data because I am getting this in text file.

Comment: @Roger Polak I am new to Python, how would you suggest to draw straight vertical lines between the columns ?

Comment: @Shadkhan example: `SEMESTER    |        24         |    18    |                  |    0         |      74       |     28      |    0       |   74     |   VISU`

Comment: @Shadkhan My only other thought on a way to approach this is to use the number of spaces between the letters on the top column to tell if something has exceeded the "expected" amount of space between two columns. Not sure if this will guarantee completely accurate results though.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will serve the purpose (using regular expression) ,

```
import re

file_in = open('test_file.txt','r')
for line in file_in:
    new_line = re.sub("\s+", ",",line.strip())
    print [new_line]
```

It gives the following output,

```
['a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j']
['SEMESTER,24,18,0,74,28,0,74,VISU']
['Burf,13+1/2,9+5/8,0,1,122,320,0,1,122,VISU']
['1ST,8+3/4,4+1/2,8,192,1,280,3,570,8,192,CBL']
['Burf,13+1/2,9+5/8,36,0,1,235,592,0,1,235,VISU']
['SEMESTER,26,16,Line,0,160,212,0,160,CALC']
['8+3/4,7,26,0,8,243,734,970,8,243,CBL']
['OPEN,WORK,6+1/8,WiseLine,8243,10,239']
['SEMESTER,19,16,line,pipe,0,105,0,0,105,CALC']
['SEMESTER,16,65#,0,100,0,89,CALC']
['2ND,6+1/8,4+1/2,0,9,257']
['SEMESTER,20,16,65#,0,89,100,0,89,CALC']
['2ND,6+1/8,4+1/2,0,9,257']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer doesn't have any "blank" columns as are required by the OP.

Comment: true!, I'm sorry.

Comment: Look at my last comment on the question... That's my only idea but I'm not good enough at regex to make it work. Maybe you can take a crack?